# If $f(x) = \frac{\cos x + 5\cos 3x + \cos 5x}{\cos 6x + 6\cos4x + 15\cos2x + 10}$then..

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $f(x) = \frac{\cos x + 5\cos 3x + \cos 5x}{\cos 6x + 6\cos4x + 15\cos2x + 10}$ then find the value of $f(0) + f'(0) + f''(0)$.

 I tried differentiating the given. But it is getting too long and complicated. So there must be a way to simplify $f(x)$. What is it?

Comment: may be you mean in numerator $\cos 5x+5\cos 3x+10 \cos x$

Comment: $f(0)=\frac7{32}$ and as the function is even, $f'(0)=0$. The rest is up to you :)

Comment: The final answer is coming to be (-11/16), isn't it? Please, somebody confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can simplify the fraction as $$\frac{2\cos3x\cos2x+5\cos3x}{2\cos^23x-1+6[2\cos3x\cos x]+9\cos2x+10}$$
$$=\frac{(2\cos2x+5)\cos3x}{2\cos^23x+12\cos3x\cos x+18\cos^2x}$$
$$=\frac{(2\cos2x+5)\cos3x}{2(\cos3x+3\cos x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{[2(2c^2-1)+5](4c^3-3c)}{2(4c^3)^2}$$
$$=\frac{(4c^2+3)(4c^2-3)}{32c^5}$$
$$=\frac 12\sec x-\frac{9}{32}\sec^5x$$

Now you can differentiate this twice quite easily

Comment: This is a nice simplification, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = \frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$

so $f(x) v(x) = u(x)$

Differentiating gives: $f'(x) v(x) + v'(x) f(x) = u'(x)$

Differentiating again: $f''(x) v(x) + f'(x) v'(x) + v''(x)f(x)+f'(x)v'(x) = u''(x)$

Setting $x=0$ and noticing $u'(0)=v'(0)=0$ (only $\sin$ terms appear in the derivatives) gives:

$f'(0)v(0)=0 \Rightarrow f'(0)=0$

Then $f''(0)v(0)+v''(0)f(0)=u''(0)$ and finally:

$f''(0)=\frac{u''(0)-v''(0)f(0)}{v(0)}$

I'll let you compute $f(0)$,$v(0)$, $u''(0)$ and $v''(0)$ which is elementary.

Answer (score 3):

A "simple" way could be to consider Taylor series; start using $$\cos(y)=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{24}+O\left(y^6\right)$$ and replace $y$ by what is required.

Doing it, the numerator should be $$7-\frac{71 x^2}{2}+\frac{1031 x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ and the denominator $$32-96 x^2+128 x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Now, long division.

When you get the result, remember that $$f(x)=f(0)+x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Just identify the terms to get $f(0)$, $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$.

**Edit**

As Yves Daoust commented, it will be sufficient to use $$\cos(y)=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ This makes the work much faster.

**Update**

We may suppose that, for this problem, the coefficients were selected in order to allow nice trigonometric simplifications such as David Quinn's ones.

Let us take the most general case of $$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^m a_i \cos(i x)}{\sum_{i=0}^n b_i \cos(i x)}$$ Using the same approach as in this answer we shall have $$f(x)=\frac{A_0+A_1 x^2+O\left(x^4\right)}{B_0+B_1 x^2+O\left(x^4\right)}=\frac{A_0}{B_0}+\frac{A_1B_0-A_0B_1}{B_0^2}x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$ using $$A_0=\sum _{i=0}^m a_i\qquad A_1=-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{i=0}^m i^2 a_i\qquad B_0=\sum _{i=0}^n b_i\qquad B_1=-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{i=0}^n i^2 b_i\qquad$$

Comment: Hi Claude. Excellent approach! Isn't it enough to develop to the quadratic term ? And as we will get $(a+bx^2)/(c+dx^2)$, this yields $a/c(1+(b/a-d/c)x^2)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Thank you. I suppose it is. I have the bad tendency to always use one extra term just in case of possible cancellations.

Comment: I know what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a way to simplify f(x) to make it easy to differentiate, however one way to make the differentiation less labour intensive is to express $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ in terms of the derivatives of the numerator and denominator.

Beginning from  $f(x)=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$

Using the quotient rule

$f'(x)=\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}$

Applying the quotient, product, and chain rules

$f''(x)=\frac{v^2(v'u'+vu''-v'u'-uv'')-2vv'(vu'-uv')}{v^4}$

If you calculate $u(0), u'(0),u''(0)$ and $v(0), v'(0),v''(0)$ then it is straightforward to find the second derivative of $f$

Answer (score 1):

We can try to simplify the fraction using trigonometric formulae :

$$\cos (x) + 5\cos (3x) + \cos (5x)=\cos(x) (2 \cos(2 x)-1) (2 \cos(2 x)+5)$$ 
and $$\cos (6x) + 6\cos(4x) + 15\cos(2x) + 10=32 \cos^6(x)$$

So $$f(x)=\frac{(2 \cos(2 x)-1) (2 \cos(2 x)+5)}{32\cos^5(x)}=\frac{4\cos^2(2x)+8\cos(2x)-5}{32\cos^5(x)}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{32}(5 (12 \cos^2(2 x)-5) \tan(x) \sec^5(x)-48 \sin(2 x) \cos(2 x) \sec^5(x))\\=\frac{1}{32}\sec^5(x)(5 (12 \cos^2(2 x)-5) \tan(x)-48 \sin(2 x) \cos(2 x) )$$

But the calculation of $f''(x)$ is still pretty tedious...

Answer (score 1):

Try to simplify the denominator of f(x):

Note that by the identity $\cos(2t)=2\cos^2t-1$
$$
\cos(3t)+6\cos(2t)+15\cos t+10=4\cos^3t+12\cos^2t+12\cos t+4=4(\cos t+1)^3
$$
so 
$$
\cos(6x)+6\cos(4x)+15\cos(2x)+10=4(\cos(2x)+1)^3
$$
Therefore
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{\cos x}{(\cos(2x)+1)^3}}^{(1)}+\frac{5}{4}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{\cos(3x)}{(\cos(2x)+1)^3}}^{(2)}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{\cos(5x)}{(\cos(2x)+1)^3}}^{(3)}
$$
Now, in order to compute $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ compute $(i)'$ and $(i)''$ for each $i\in\{1,2,3\}$. Then assign $x=0$.